# C# Image.FromStream is that secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

after reading the data from the request as Stream i needed to convert it to Image so i used this Method:

```
Stream inputStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
Image img = Image.FromStream(inputStream)
```

my question is, while im unable to know what was in that inputStream (file format is done already but still..) there may be a virus or malware, so in that case FromStream(Stream) would throw ArgumentException. since it's not an image.

my question is - If the file uploaded contains a virus, and the method throws an exception while trying to convert the stream to Image, did that make any harm to the server?
if so, how to avoid it? what should be the scenario for handling file upload in the server?

Comment: It is .NET. You have to ask Microsoft I guess...

Comment: I'd vote to close, but none of the reasons listed really apply.  I'd suggest you go ahead and close this question yourself and open one over at security.stackexchange.com asking about best practices for file uploads with regards to buffer overflows.  It is an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if we could answer this with any certainty (which we can't, because unknown vulnerabilities are *unknown*, and if it was a known vulnerability, Microsoft would presumably have fixed it) it would be irresponsible to post details of an exploit here.  If I knew of an attack vector via `Image.FromStream` (or any part of the .NET framework, or really any other way) the responsible thing to do would be to report it to the vendor (MSFT in this case) and wait for them to fix it.

Basically, you need to trust that Microsoft has examined the edge conditions of parsing image data and ensured that there are no native buffer overflow or other similar vulnerabilities in that code.  Something that Microsoft has admittedly made mistakes at in the past, but in all fairness has gotten much much better at addressing over the past few years.

Comment: +1: Shy of actually hacking the `.FromStream()` method to come up with an attack vector, this is the only sensible answer.

Comment: Thanks. so in that case i dont really need a virus scan, for the photo-uploading. i'll get it for free from that function, isnt it?

Comment: That isn't what I said (or what you asked!).  A virus scanner works by intercepting the operating system's file I/O functions and scanning the files for known patterns that indicate malicious intent (thus the need for virus definition files).  None of that applies here, because as far as the code you posted is concerned, the file is only ever in memory, where a virus scanner would probably not see it.  You are right to be concerned about an attack vector here, especially if native code is used to parse the image data, but it doesn't say anything for or against the need for a virus scanner.

Comment: but if the file uploaded is not an image file - it will fail on the convert.  my question just came to me after a code-review i made to my application and reveal of vulnerabilities in it, so im just looking for the right way to secure my photo upload.